# Vonnegut's "Address at Rededication of Wheaton College Library, 1973"

Tags: setting, kurt-vonnegut

This essay was published in (perhaps among other places) in "Wampeters Foma and Granfalloons". There are two Wheaton Colleges in the U.S., one in Norton MA and the other in Wheaton IL. Does anyone know (and can you provide a reference) as to which of these two colleges this address was delivered at?

Comment: [You aren't the only person who is confused](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-wheaton-college-hate-mail-confusion-20160114-story.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be the one in Massachusetts. The essay is frequently cited as being published in [Wheaton College alumnae magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=rm5r4pBzPzAC&pg=PA508&lpg=PA508&dq=%22Wheaton%20College%20alumnae%20magazine%22&source=bl&ots=bW9Eqqaw0O&sig=sdcY_iHotcBWCaM8TCCXUnVPIg0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje1a7ducDTAhUJ5yYKHSKUBDkQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Wheaton%20College%20alumnae%20magazine%22&f=false), which is the magazine of the Wheaton College in Massachusetts.

I note, however, that the library's [own history page](http://wheatoncollege.edu/college-history/1920s/wallace-library/) does not make any mention of a rededication in 1973. There was a renaming of a room after a key alumna in 1972.

Comment: I too checked the library page at the Wheaton (MA) college and saw no reference to a rededication. 1973 was a while ago, though, so I could easily imagine that it was forgotten when the webpage was written.

Comment: @rogerl it's weird though, because you would think they would brag about someone as famous as Vonnegut being at their rededication.

Comment: In the Wheaton College Alumnae Magazine, it was titled "Essay for the Wheaton Library". It sounds as if he wrote the essay, but didn't actually appear there. That would make sense, since I gather he made few public appearances. I don't know why he would have permitted the re-titling when it was published in his book; perhaps he simply forgot?

Comment: @JoshuaEngel Interesting point. He does end with "Thus ends my speech. I thank you.", though.